# 1986 pontiac grand prix won't start

Tags: starting, pontiac, grand-prix

What could be wrong if car will not start after jumping it for 10 minutes. Radio and lights turn on but car will not start. No noise whatsoever

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I take it the engine will turn over (cranks), but no sign of life (will not start)? What have you checked? Does it have fuel? Do you hear the fuel pump whine when you first turn the ignition switch on? Is there spark at the spark plugs?

Comment: The battery could be dead as a hammer and cause this regardless of attempted charging or jumping. Other than that the 80's gm cars were prone to ignition switch failure or burn out, that or the starter solenoid itself has failed, replace the whole starter is best practice when the solenoid fail as it is part of the starter.